# Analyzing LC circuit with multiple inductors and capacitors

Tags: passive-networks

I have a problem understanding what's going on in a more complicated LC circuits with multiple inductors and capacitors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRzjK4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with the two capacitors having the same size and the two inductors different. How can I evaluate the resonance frequency of that circuit?

Comment: Inductance doubles, capacitance halves, no change in resonant frequency.

Comment: This is not a 'more complicated' circuit. The inductors are in series. The capacitors are in series. Combine them in series into one inductor, and one capacitor, and then evaluate the frequency in the straightforward way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify.

That means, look at subcircuits.

What is the difference between these two circuits? Is there any?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQCnmv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answering that may let you redraw the original circuit in a form that is simpler to analyse.

I assume that mutual coupling between the inductors is small enough to be ignored, since it isn't mentioned in the question...

(Apart from the schematics, I think this ought to be a comment. Oh well.)